# How to get the logged user with an OWIN authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

The login code in my **AccountController**

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();  
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name+" "+user.Surname));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Code));
var claimIdenties = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, claimIdenties);
```

In my **PrivateController** I want to access to the Id of the authenticated user, I'm searching an ID field or something like that but

[image]

How to get the logged user with an OWIN authentication?

**Edit**

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity
```

Gives me access to the following propertys:

- AuthenticationType
- IsAuthenticated
- Name //Claim.Name

How can I set an ID like a 'Claim.ID' and retrieve it?

**Second edit**

This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/24893167/4470880 solved my problem.

Comment: `this.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User`? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270723(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: So the comment above will get you the `ClaimsPrincipal`... from this you can `principal.FindFirst(claimType)?.Value`, where the default `id` claim type (in aspnet identity, most likely others too) is `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this alternative:

```
var user = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
```

For getting name of the `user`:

```
string name = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/, in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace, there are extension methods to get the user's ID and Name -- see [MSDN IdentityExtensions Class (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions(v=vs.111).aspx)

usage is like this (from a controller):

```
string userId = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write something like that :

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected ApplicationUser CurrentUser
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
                    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
                    .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()); 
            }
    }

    //...
}
```

So you write a `BaseController` which inherits from `Controller`.
Then, all your controllers will heritate from `BaseController` ; so you could use `CurrentUser.Id` in all your controllers